# Facebook sdk Java - adding extended permissions with LoginButton

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app works well, but I also would like to list the pages I admin in Facebook. I add the `manage_pages` permission, to the login, and then I want to list the pages.

It works well on the Facebook Graph API Exlorer-

```
 SELECT manage_pages FROM permissions WHERE uid = me()
```

I got `manage_pages=1`. Then I listed my pages-

```
 SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid =me()
```

I get all the page ids I admin.

But in my app I tried to add the `manage_pages` permission, and when I check the permissions in the app I get `manage_pages=0`

Here are a few line of my code:

```
LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("manage_pages"));
String fqlQuery = "SELECT manage_pages FROM permissions WHERE uid = me()";
Log.d("LINK_RESULT", (String) object.get("manage_pages"));
```

I get `manage_pages=0`, but when I change it to "email", I get `email=1`

How do I add the extended permissions to the LoginButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the section **Request publish permissions** in [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/#permissions-publish). It says that `manage_pages` is a publish permission. Its not a read permission!

Another thing- With the new SDKs, you need to **separate** the read and the write permissions. You can first open session for read, get what you want and then open for publish. According to the facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginButton/)-

> If any publish permissions are included, the login attempt by the user will fail. The LoginButton can only be associated with either read permissions or publish permissions, but not both. Calling both setReadPermissions and setPublishPermissions on the same instance of LoginButton will result in an exception being thrown unless clearPermissions is called in between.

You need to call `clearPermissions()` in between the two calls. Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: I am not requesting now any read permissions, only the publish permissions, I still cleared the permissions,

Comment: So? is it working or not? If not, did you see any dialog for the `manage_pages` permission?

Comment: I do not see a dialog for the manage_pages, it only asks for the default permissions.

Comment: You used `setPublishPermissions` right? or setReadPermissions`?

Comment: loginButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("manage_pages"));

Comment: How do I set the permission after the initial login dialog?

Comment: See, try this- `authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info"));` then `clearPer... ` then `setPublishPermissions`

Comment: But the thing is facebook recommends to ask for the publish permissions at the actual time of publishing, not jusk asking both permissions one after the other. [Here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious/SelectionFragment.java#L206) is a recommended way of implementing the login. (checkout the `handleannounce` method in the example)

Comment: My code is simple, I set the permission and then I call Session.openActiveSession. When do I make the second permission call? is there an example out there?

Comment: the link I gave you - [Link](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious/SelectionFragment.java#L206) is a better way to handle this thing. 

What you are trying to do- I've never implemented but just a guess- whenever you are trying to do posting, clear the permission and call  the `setPublishPermissions` dialog, just a gut feeling but it should work!

Comment: I did       loginButton.clearPermissions();
         loginButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("manage_pages"));
Then I call  Session.openActiveSession. I don't get a dialog for the new pemissions, just the default dialog.

Comment: I got it it works, I added these lines after the initial login, right after it logs in, and gets the user.       LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
      loginButton.clearPermissions();
         loginButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("manage_pages"));

Comment: Am glad you cracked it. :)